# Fetch all first child elements from a table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, selectors-api

Pretty simple I need to fetch all first type of th elements text :

```
<html>
<body>

  <table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line #1</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line #2</td>
    <td>SLD</td>
    <td>68</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line #3</td>
    <td>MDK</td>
    <td>68</td>
  </tr>
</table> 

<script type="text/javascript">

console.log(document.querySelectorAll('table tr td:first-of-type'));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to fetch all table tr td:first-of-type innertext... small tweak needed here.

Comment: Are you asking the correct question. There is only one 'table tr th:first-child' in the code you provided. The rest are 'td''s.

Comment: Edited to td :)

Comment: your td and th has no child elements. do you think about `th:first-of-type`?

Comment: Not the correct syntax but just to get the idea console.log(document.querySelectorAll('table tr td:first-of-type').innertext); (pure js no jquery)

Comment: So what seems to be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it somehow... trail and error... Thanks :)

```
<html>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Line #1</td>
            <td>MKD</td>
            <td>68</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Line #2</td>
            <td>SLD</td>
            <td>32</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Line #3</td>
            <td>HAD</td>
            <td>53</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Line #4</td>
            <td>LRD</td>
            <td>49</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var theFirstChilds = document.querySelectorAll('table tr td:first-of-type');
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < theFirstChilds.length; ++i) {
            console.log(theFirstChilds[i].innerText);
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To make it in single line `console.log.apply(null, Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('table tr td:first-of-type'), function(x){return x.innerText;}))`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you  meant

```
document.querySelectorAll('table tr td:first-child')
```

Answer (score 0):

> table tr td:first-child

As Dan Philip mentioned, you need to adjust your HTML like below.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Line #1</td>
    <td>Lastname</td>
    <td>Age</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line #2</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line #3</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a Codepen.io example using jquery (just to illustrate):

https://codepen.io/wykydtronik/pen/yMGMYw

```
$( "table tr td:first-child" )
  .css( "text-decoration", "underline" )
  .hover(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "gogreen" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "gogreen" );
  });

var theFirstChilds = document.querySelectorAll('table tr td:first-child');

console.log(theFirstChilds[0]);
console.log(theFirstChilds[1]);
console.log(theFirstChilds[2]);
```

Note the jQuery is just an example of what you're attempting to do. On codepen you can open up the console at the bottom to see what the objects stored from the node.